# @bind e @onchange para um select no blazor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

olá, sou novo com blazor eu queria fazer o seguinte. tenho 2 Listas, Categoria e uma outra Lista2, no formulário tenho 1 select para o categoria e outro select para a Lista2, e queria fazer com que ao mudar a option selecionada da categoria, mudasse a listagem do select da Lista2(os dados contem foreign key cd_categoria). Ex: seleciono categoria1, e os options do select da Lista2 vai mudar de acordo com a categoria selecionada. eu já tenho uma função para fazer esse filtro, então como eu faria com que o select categoria chamasse essa funcao (listarPorCategoriaSelecionada(int cd_categoriaSelecionada){}) ao ser selecionado determinado option? pois vou precisar tanto da categoria selecionada, como da opção selecionada da lista2.

Comment: Não precisa explicar o exmplo, apresente o seu código para termos um [mcve]

Comment: E ai a resposta te ajudou?

Answer (score 0):

No Blazor só precisa que o elemento `<select>` tenha um `bind` para a troca das informações no segundo `<select>`, um exemplo básico que ilustra uma situação básica:

Classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

essas duas classes são utilizadas da seguinte forma, após escolher a `Category` faz um filtro em `SubCategory` com relação a sua chave `CategoryId`.

No código `blazor`:

```
<h3>Select</h3>
<div>
  <select @bind="CategoryId">
    <option value="0">Selecione</option>
    @foreach (var category in Categories)
    {
      <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
    }
  </select>
  @CategoryId
  <select>
    @foreach (var subCategory in SubCategories.Where(c => c.CategoryId == CategoryId))
    {
      <option value="@subCategory.Id">@subCategory.Name</option>
    }
  </select>
</div>
@code {
  public int CategoryId { get; set; } = 0;
  List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
  List<SubCategory> SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Alimento" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Remedio" });

    SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 1, Name = "Arroz", CategoryId = 1 });
    SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 2, Name = "Feijão", CategoryId = 1 });
    SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 3, Name = "Pão", CategoryId = 1 });

    SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 4, Name = "ASS", CategoryId = 2 });
    SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 5, Name = "Doril", CategoryId = 2 });
  }    
}
```

Explicação do código:

São criados 3 variáveis `CategoryId`, `Categories` e `SubCategories` respectivamente um inteiro e duas listas que são preenchidas manualmente na inicialização do componente.

No primeiro `select` se carrega normalmente todas as `Categories` e no segundo `select` se faz um filtro para carregar-lo com `CategoryId`. Todas as vezes que essa variável trocar de valor o componente atualiza e muda as caixas subsequentes só configurando na caixa das categorias `@bind="CategoriaId"` e assim já fica pronto o seu filtro dinâmico.

---

Um outra forma `onChange`, esse em questão dá mais controle sobre outro `select`, porque nesse pode até já posicionar o elemento carregado, então vai depender do que necessita, exemplo:

```
h3>Select</h3>
<div>
  <select value="@CategoryId" @onchange="@ChangeCategory">
    <option value="0">Selecione</option>
    @foreach (var category in Categories)
    {
      <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
    }
  </select>
  @CategoryId
  <select @bind="SubCategoryId">
    @foreach (var subCategory in SubCategoriesResults)
    {
      <option value="@subCategory.Id">@subCategory.Name</option>
    }
  </select>
  @SubCategoryId
</div>
@code {

    public int CategoryId { get; set; } = 0;
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
    List<SubCategory> SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
    List<SubCategory> SubCategoriesResults = new List<SubCategory>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
      Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Alimento" });
      Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Remedio" });

      SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 1, Name = "Arroz", CategoryId = 1 });
      SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 2, Name = "Feijão", CategoryId = 1 });
      SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 3, Name = "Pão", CategoryId = 1 });

      SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 4, Name = "ASS", CategoryId = 2 });
      SubCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 5, Name = "Doril", CategoryId = 2 });

      SubCategoriesResults.Clear();
    }

    Task ChangeCategory(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
      SubCategoryId = 0;
      SubCategoriesResults.Clear();
      CategoryId = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
      if (CategoryId > 0)
      {
        SubCategoriesResults = SubCategories
              .Where(c => c.CategoryId == CategoryId)
              .ToList();
        if (SubCategoriesResults.Any())
        {
          SubCategoryId = SubCategoriesResults[0].Id;
        }
      }
      StateHasChanged();
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```